# Boost ASIO : Document not complete

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am using the following template code for a Boost ASIO socket listener:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 88));

    for (;;)
    {
      tcp::socket socket(io_service);
      acceptor.accept(socket);

      std::string message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>HELLO WORLD</h1></body></html>";

      boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
      boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
    }
  } catch (std::exception& e) { std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl; }

  return 0;
}
```

And it works fine when I view it in a browser.

But when I look try to read it from another app (such as HTTP.request in Node.JS) it fails with a Parse Error. If I look at it via https://validator.w3.org,  it says "I/O Error: The result cannot be determined due to a non-document-error".

Comment: HTTP strictly requires a properly formed header. What you have done is just written a minimal HTML payload. Since there is no HTTP (note the difference - HTTP is a transport, HTML is a document description format), software that demands strict conformance to HTTP (such as node.js) reject the stream since it's invalid.

Comment: Thanks for that.  From what I read, HTTP doesn't have any requirements for a header.  (In other words, while it's just the HTML payload, I still don't see how it's not perfectly valid HTTP.)  But regardless, when I do add Content-type, etc. it doesn't change the error.

Comment: @DavidBroderick: Richard is right. Your data is a valid HTTP body (e.g: HTML), but not a valid HTTP response (HTTP status line, plus headers, plus body, etc). An HTTP response may contain an HTTP body. Example of valid HTTP responses can be seen in your browser's console (if it has one), or at [HTTP basics](http://learn.onemonth.com/understanding-http-basics), or just Google for it. Example, to respond with HELLO, you can send something like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\n\r\nHELLO`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  I was formatting the header wrong and so I had ruled it out as the cause.  Thanks to you and Richard, both.

Answer (score 2):

See HTTP specification (RFC7230) page 19, Section 3 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-19)

the format for an HTTP message is:

```
 HTTP-message   = start-line
                  *( header-field CRLF )
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```

Further reading will reveal the restrictions and requirements of the start line, formatting of headers and the requirement to indicate to the receiver the length of the message body (or a means to detect it in the case of a chunked message)

The code above is formatted as follows:

```
[ message-body ]
```

Comment: That was it, Richard.  Thank you!